# Equivalent definitions for node

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

For a plane curve $C$ defined by $F(x,y)$ containing $0$, we say $0$ is a node if one of the following conditions satisfied:

1. The tangent cone (i.e. the variety defined by the lowest degree part of $F$) is defined by non-degenerate quadratic form
2. The completion of local ring $\hat{\mathcal O}_{C,0}$ is isomorphic to $k[[x,y]]/(Q)$ where $Q$ non-degenerate quadratic.

I want to know why they are equivalent?

Answer (score 2):

For simplicity, let us assume that we are working over an algebraically closed field. Then, any non-degenerate quadratic form can be assumed to be $xy$ after a change of variables. In $k[[x,y]]$, a power series of the form $xy+$ higher order terms can be seen to be product of two power series of the form $x+$ higher order and $y+$ higher order. So, these two can be taken as the generators of the power series ring and so we are done. Converse is just using the identification $k[x,y]/(x,y)^3=k[[x,y]]/(x,y)^3$.

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake in the condition 2: it should be $k[[x,y]]/(Q)$. And could you please explain why the curve defined by $xy=0$ satisfies $\hat{\mathcal O}_C,0=k[[x,y]]/(xy)$? (should be some basic commutative algebra)